# Is there a way to get a list of all in-progress rooms with their participants in one request?

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

Right now I loop through every in-progress room and send a request to get participants, which really slows down the site. is there any other way?

And also is there a way to filter rooms by number of participants, e.g. get all rooms with one participant?